# Get the complete width of a container that overflows off of the screen

Tags: javascript, css

How can I work out the full width of a container where the contents overflow off of the screen?

Here is an example of what I mean - http://jsfiddle.net/TFdLA/. In reality, `.inner` has no width set so takes up all of the available width on the screen.

However, if I use `$('.inner').innerWidth();` I just get the width of the screen, where as what I would like is the width that `.inner` would take up if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `$('.inner')[0].scrollWidth` or

```
$('.inner').each(function(){
    this.scrollWidth;
})
```

which is probably what you need.

[Here with your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TFdLA/1/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your CSS file defines `.inner{ width:300px }`

Comment: From my question - "In reality, `.inner` has no width set so takes up all of the available width on the screen." Thanks.